# What classes to put the progress bar code in?

Tags: java, android, main-activity

I am building a circular progress bar with the library that can be found here on [github](https://github.com/lopspower/CircularProgressBar). And I have gotten the circle to display with the xml given and added the dependencies to the build.gradle. Along with adding the correct attrs and the dimes to properly generate it. But I am having trouble when it comes to the java file the code that is supposed to go there is CircularProgressBar circularProgressBar =

```
(CircularProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.yourCircularProgressbar);
circularProgressBar.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.progressBarColor));
circularProgressBar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.backgroundProgressBarColor));
circularProgressBar.setProgressBarWidth(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.progressBarWidth));
circularProgressBar.setBackgroundProgressBarWidth(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.backgroundProgressBarWidth));
int animationDuration = 2500; // 2500ms = 2,5s
circularProgressBar.setProgressWithAnimation(65, animationDuration); // Default duration = 1500ms
```

However I don't know where to put it. I have tried putting it in the onCreate of the MainActivity. But that throws an error?

Added XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/hydration">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="59dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:onClick="eight"
            android:text="8"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_marginBottom="53dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/quantity_text_view"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/quantity_text_view" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="59dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:onClick="thirty_two"
            android:text="32"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/quantity_text_view" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="59dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:onClick="sixteen"
            android:text="16.9"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button3" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:text="Total"
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <com.mikhaellopez.circularprogressbar.CircularProgressBar
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:cpb_background_progressbar_color="#FFCDD2"
        app:cpb_background_progressbar_width="5dp"
        app:cpb_progressbar_color="#F44336"
        app:cpb_progressbar_width="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/circle_progressbar"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ProgressBar
        style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:progress="56"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="42dp" />

    <ProgressBar
        style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:progress="78"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="56dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:text="Daily"
        android:layout_above="@+id/progressBar2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_marginBottom="28dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:text="Activity"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The Added StackTrace

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.mikhaellopez.circularprogressbar.CircularProgressBar.setColor(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                       at com.oxinc.android.hydro.MainActivity$override.Circle(MainActivity.java:32)
                                                                       at com.oxinc.android.hydro.MainActivity$override.access$dispatch(MainActivity.java)
                                                                       at com.oxinc.android.hydro.MainActivity.Circle(MainActivity.java:0)
                                                                       at com.oxinc.android.hydro.MainActivity$override.onCreate(MainActivity.java:83)
                                                                       at com.oxinc.android.hydro.MainActivity$override.access$dispatch(MainActivity.java)
                                                                       at com.oxinc.android.hydro.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:0)
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6245)
                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4098) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1360) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5456) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

And the full extent of the MainActivity

```
    package com.oxinc.android.hydro;

import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.TextView;

import com.mikhaellopez.circularprogressbar.CircularProgressBar;
import com.oxinc.android.hydro.layout_intializers.Hydration;
import com.oxinc.android.hydro.layout_intializers.Tips;
import com.oxinc.android.hydro.layout_intializers.Info;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public  void Circle() {
        CircularProgressBar circularProgressBar = (CircularProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.circle_progressbar);
        circularProgressBar.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.cpb_progressbar_color));
        circularProgressBar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.cpb_background_progressbar_color));
        circularProgressBar.setProgressBarWidth(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.cpb_progressbar_width));
        circularProgressBar.setBackgroundProgressBarWidth(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.cpb_background_progressbar_width));
        int animationDuration = 2500; // 2500ms = 2,5s
        circularProgressBar.setProgressWithAnimation(65, animationDuration); // Default duration = 1500ms

    }

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
//        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        Circle();

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    //Displays the sectionsm to the View

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "Hydration";
                case 1:
                    return "Info";
                case 2:
                    return "Tips";
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new Hydration();
                case 1:
                    return new Info();
                case 2:
                    return new Tips();
                default:
                    // this should never happen
                    return null;
                //return new Fragment();
            }
        }
    }

    //Executes the methods to increment by amount

    public int quantity = 0;
    public String outcome = "";
    public int required = 0;
    public int height = 0;


    public void eight(View view) {
        quantity = quantity + 8;
        displayQuantity(quantity);
    }

    public void twelve(View view) {
        quantity = quantity + 12;
        displayQuantity(quantity);
    }

    public void sixteen(View view) {
        quantity = quantity + 16;
        displayQuantity(quantity);
    }

    public void thirty_two(View view) {
        quantity = quantity + 32;
        displayQuantity(quantity);
    }

    public void sixty_four(View view) {
        quantity = quantity + 64;
        displayQuantity(quantity);
    }

    //Reset Button
    public void reset(View view) {
        quantity = 0;
        displayQuantity(quantity);
        outcome = "";
//        displayOutcome(outcome);
    }

    //Displays Quantity to the TextView
    public void displayQuantity(int quantity) {
        TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(
                R.id.quantity_text_view);
        quantityTextView.setText(quantity + "");
    }


}
```

Comment: what is the error? if its null pointer exception, it means you didn't add a CircularProgressBar with yourCircularProgressbar id to your layout.

Comment: Do you have an `xml` file where you define your `CircularProgressBar` with an id of `yourCircularProgressbar`?

Comment: @Pztar yes I do. Is it supposed to go in the onCreate method?

Comment: Can you please add the corresponding XML?

Comment: @JoaquimLey Just Added.

Comment: You're grabbing the wrong id. In your `onCreate` change your `findViewById(R.id.yourCircularProgressbar)` to '`findViewById(R.id.circle_progressbar`

Comment: It should go in or after onCreateView (such as onCreate). But please add the error message

Comment: @Fidel_Willis Is this a fragment or Activity?

Comment: @Pztar changed that still crashes

Comment: @JoaquimLey Activity

Comment: Post your `stacktrace` then

Comment: Added StackTrace and the full MainActivity

Comment: I don't see it specified in the question. Is that XML activity_main.xml or something else?

Comment: I mean, in the same Activity you're using 'findViewById(R.id.tabs)", which is not an ID in the XML you provided.

Comment: @1Up it's actually hydration.xml. I have a tabbed layout that displays three views. Hydration, Info, and Tips. But the circle progress bar goes with the hydration layout

Comment: And i guess "new Hydration()" creates your Fragment. This means that you should be finding that view inside that Fragment's onCreateView()

Comment: Just to be more specific, in your onCreateView() you should be inflating your R.layout.hydration.xml, from there use view.findViewById(R.id.circle_progressbar) to get your progressbar and do stuff with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new Hydration();
            case 1:
                return new Info();
            case 2:
                return new Tips();
            default:
                // this should never happen
                return null;
            //return new Fragment();
        }
    }
```

This part creates the Fragments for your Tabs. Each Fragment has it's own layout, and you said hydration.xml is in fact the XML you showed up there.

To be able to reference views inside your Fragment's View you need to do so inside that Fragment's onCreateView method. Else the View is not on screen by the time you try to reference it.

So, this is what I'm guessing should be inside the Hydration Fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hydration, parent, false);

    //Find your stuff from the inflated rootView of your Fragment
    CircularProgressBar progressBar = rootView.findViewById(R.id.circle_progressbar);
    //Do stuff with progressBar

    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Okay thank you seems like it will work. I'll try when home